# How to merge looped subscription data angular 2 TS

Tags: angular, angular2-observables

```
fieldRender(formSets: any[]) {

    let questions: any[] = [];
    let q: QuestionBase<any>[] = [];
    let index: number = 0;

    formSets.forEach(formSet => {
      formSet.children.forEach(child => {
        this.appointmentService.getField(child.field.uuid).subscribe(res => {
          let dataType;
          let label;
          let parent;
          let uuid;
          let answers = [];

          if (res.concept != null) {
            if (res.concept.datatype)
              dataType = res.concept.datatype.display;
            if (res.answers)
              answers = res.answers;
          }
          uuid = res.uuid;
          label = res.display;
          parent = formSet.parent.field.display;

          let question: Question = new Question();
          question.label = label;
          question.type = dataType;
          question.parent = parent;
          question.uuid = uuid;
          question.answers = answers;

          questions.push(question);

          console.log("Questions", JSON.stringify(questions));
        });
      });
    });

  }
```

This is my function.What i want this function to return Observable of Questions which i can subscribe to get data anywhere.
FormSets is an array of FormSet
FormSet contains a parent and a children array

Answer (score 0):

If formSet.children is an array, you can do something similar to thi

```
Rx.Observable.from(formSet.children)
.flatMap((child) => this.appointmentService.getField(child.field.uuid))
.subscribe((question) => questions.push(question))
```

this way you can have all the responses from getField in one "stream"

You don't give us much context so I'm guessing ;)

Comment: Hey @rick thanks for the response i have edited the post added some more of the code and a bit more context..

Comment: have you tried my solution? if you need an observable as output you can create your question inside a map instead of subscribe